# Categorical Variable content in world map in tableau

Tags: variables, tableau-api

I have listed a sample data set. I need to get details of the different elements in the categorical variable over the map while hovering over the countries.

--Dragging and dropping the categorical variable just displays the values for the first element.

the variables used are:
country (geographic)
sales (numeric)
furniture (containing 'table' and 'chair')

I need to get details of sales of chairs and tables over the country on the map while hovering over the countries.

Thanks for the help
[the sample data set as seen in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csSc5.png)

Comment: did my below answer assist ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the creating a graph in a tooltip hack to solve this problem. The issue is that the Level of Detail of your data does not support the visualisation you want to make.

Do the following:
1) Create cohort calculated fields: You need to separate a measure so that it is specific to one member in a dimension (basically a cross tab). 
For you this means creating a calculated field per furniture type. 
e.g. `Chair Sales Cohort =
 if [Furniture] = 'chair'
then [Sales]
END`
Repeat this for each furniture type

You can then drag each of these onto the tooltip pane and you will have tooltips :)

If you wanted to get fancy follow step 2 and 3 from this link to make it a bar chart instead of just a number in a tooltip. [make a bar chart in tableau](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#formatting_tooltips_barchart_example.html)

Good luck !